# How to Clear all the worksheet contents except for the specified cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have an worksheet where I have few data's, I have created a button which is used to clear the data. The current code which I have written will clear all the data starting from "E2" Cell to the end of the worksheet. 
I have a data in "R2" cell which I don't want to clear. 
Is there any way to achieve the above requirement (Delete from 'E2' till the rest of the worksheet but don't clear the contents of 'R2' cell).

Below is by Code :

```
  Private Sub CommandButton25_Click()
  Range("E2:XFD1048576").ClearContents  ' but I don't want R2 cell to be Cleared
  End Sub()
```

Comment: Like: `Private Sub CommandButton25_Click(): Dim holder As String: holder = Range("R2").Formula: Range("E2:XFD1048576").ClearContents: Range("R2").Formula = holder: End Sub`? Or simply: `Range("E2:Q2,S2:XFD2,E3:XFD1048576").ClearContents`

Comment: @DirkReichel Thanks a ton, it worked!

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub CommandButton25_Click()
  temp = Range("R2").Value
  Range("E2:XFD1048576").ClearContents
  Range("R2").Value = temp
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Animesh!

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub CommandButton25_Click()
    Dim tableRange As Range: Set tableRange = Range("E2:XFD1048576")
    Dim IgnoreCells As Range: 
Set IgnoreCells = Application.Union(IgnoreCells, tableRange.Range("R2"))
    Dim xlCell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.Iteration = False
    For Each xlCell In tableRange.Cells
        If Application.Intersect(xlCell, IgnoreCells) Is Nothing Then
            Call xlCell.ClearContents
        End If
        DoEvents
    Next

    Application.Iteration = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```